# Hyper V with local storage and backup thoughts?

Tags: hyper-v

We would like to consolidate 3 of our existing Windows 2000 servers to 3 VM's running on a Hyper V host.
We were looking at using local storage for all 3vm's with a Raid 10 configuration. We also wanted to get some ideas on backup what type of redundancy we can use with the Hyper V?

Sorry for being bland about this, but we are new to the virutalization world and wanted to see which are the best options of consolidating these servers with a low budget.

The servers will are running our PRI DOM CONTROLLER, BKUP DOM CONTROLLER and SQL server.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to have a single host then local (DAS) storage is the right way, as is RAID 10 - you'll get plenty of performance from that configuration (remember you'll need plenty of memory too, but at least that's cheap). As for backup, well as a 'good enough' solution perhaps just two or three of those quite cheap USB external disks cycled between on-site and off-site should be ok I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

> The servers will are running our PRI
>   DOM CONTROLLER, BKUP DOM CONTROLLER
>   and SQL server.

Bad. Stating the obvious: if that physical box fails - how you cope with loosing what seems to be all of you domain controllers? If you can - good. If not - you mnow - get TWO servers and SPLIT THE RISK.

Answer (score 0):

Do not run the domain controllers as VMs.  The domain controllers are the core of the network and if you loose the host you are dead in the water.  Always keep 2 DCs on two physical servers.

Local storage for VMs is fine as long as you only have that one VM host.  The best way to backup Hyper-V VMs is to use System Center Data Protection Manager 2010 but it also requires it's own physical server (nothings ever easy).  DPM is free as long as you buy the server management license for the server(s) you want to back up.

Also consider licensing for the VM host.  I'd strongly suggest purchasing the 2K8R2 datacenter license for each processor.  This allows you to host an unlimited number of windows servers without having to buy more OS licenses.